# Android: Update ListView from EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

friends.

I have an app module that implements State pattern. Idea is:
1. User enter the Date -->
2. Screen changes to a ne state: dynamically inflates ListView and asks user to fill the list with some data

Problem is that when I call notifyDataSetChange() from update method 2nd time, EditText view doens't want to do its functions anymore.

This is a string from a logcat, that I think contains key of my problem.

*09-10 10:33:38.937 26954-26954/com.example.android.turtleinfo D/ListView: change accessibility focus position = 0*

Here are codes for everything.

**1. My State Pattern Super Class**

```
public abstract class ScreenState
    {

        public BuilderActivity activity;



        public ScreenState(BuilderActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            //initializeScreen(activity);
        }

        public abstract void initializeScreen(Activity activity);
        public abstract void switchState();
        public abstract void updateText(View view);


        public void addTextWatcher(EditText text) {
            text.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        activity.state.updateText(v);

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

**2. Implementation of initialize screen and updateData methods**

```
@Override
    public void initializeScreen(Activity activity) {

        ((BuilderActivity) activity).editText.setHint("Name");
        addTextWatcher(((BuilderActivity) activity).editText);
        textView = (TextView)activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.schedule_text_style, null);
        textView.setHeight(100);
        screenText = "End Date: " + new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(((BuilderActivity) activity).data.getEndDate())+"\n\n";

        textView.setText(screenText+"\n");
        ((BuilderActivity) activity).scheduleLayout.addView(textView);

        ((BuilderActivity) activity).data.setNames(new ArrayList<String>());

        lv = (ListView)activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_text_style, null);
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        adapt = new ArrayAdapter<>(super.activity, R.layout.schedule_text_style, listItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapt);
        ((BuilderActivity) activity).scheduleLayout.addView(lv);


    }
```

---

```
@Override
public void updateText(View view) {

    String text = activity.editText.getText().toString();

    if (text.length() >= 2) {
        if (!activity.data.names.contains(text)) {
            activity.data.addToList(text);



            listItems.add(text);
            adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();

            activity.editText.setText("");
            counter++;
            activity.editText.setText("");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "same names are not allowed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ((BuilderActivity) activity).editText.setText("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "name should contain 2 or more symbols",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((BuilderActivity) activity).editText.setText("");
    }

}
```

This is how it looks on device.

**1. First insertion is ok**

[image]

**2.** And second and further insertionas are impossible. OK softkeyboard button switches first to NEXT button[image]

**3.** If I click next, EditText looses focus, nothing happens, but NEXT button Switches to '/n' button.

[image]

So, please, if anyone know, what am I doing worng, help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
public void addTextWatcher(EditText text)
```

function.

Look at the **android:imeActionId** and **android:imeOptions attributes**, plus the **setOnEditorActionListener() method**, all on TextView/Edittext.

You can also change the text of the keyboard button by using this.

```
mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Your text", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```